# Pass [Error 5] Access is denied

Tags: python

I'm trying to copy files in my USB with a program. But it seems like the USB contains "System Volume Information" folder and my program crash every time because of "[Error 5] Access is denied". I just want to delete all files and folders except the "System Volume Information".. How can i achieve this?

Here's the code that make it crash:

```
def copy(src, dest):
try:
    shutil.copytree(src, dest)
    print "Data Transfer Finished.."
except OSError as e:
    # If the error was caused because the source wasn't a directory
    if e.errno == errno.ENOTDIR:
        shutil.copy(src, dst)
        print "Copy succeed"
    if e.errno == errno.EACCES:
        pass
except WindowsError:
    if e.errno == errno.EACCES:
        pass
    else:
        print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)
```

I tried using errno.EACCESS but it's just the same

Comment: What is `e`?  `except WindowsError as e:`  What happens to all the other `WindowsError`s?  Are you sure you have caught the right exception?  Please show the error output and traceback.

Comment: So you are asking us to find the issue in your program that you have not posted? It should be simple. let me try

Comment: There you go, i added the code...

Comment: What is the error? Can you please post full traceback?

Comment: Well, thanks for your time... I just figured out how..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm searching for solution in google and i found out how, here's the code..

```
def copy(src, dest):
try:
    shutil.copytree(src, dest, ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("System Volume Information"))
    print "Data Transfer Finished.."
except OSError as e:
    # If the error was caused because the source wasn't a directory
    if e.errno == errno.ENOTDIR:
        shutil.copy(src, dst)
        print "Copy succeed"
    if e.errno == errno.EACCES:
        pass
except WindowsError:
    if e.errno == errno.EACCES:
        pass
    else:
        print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)
```

It will ignore the "System Volume Information" folder.. xD 

Thank you for everyone that tried to help me..